# In Eclipse, how can I show generic type constraints in Javadocs?

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, constraints, javadoc

In Eclipse, when you hover on an element, only the Javadoc shows, and the element's (unconstrained) signature.

Suppose I have a `class X <T extends Object> {}`.  If I use Eclipse's Javadoc generator, I get:

```
/**
 * @param <T>
 */
```

The rendered Javadoc looks like this.  Note the lack of type constraint information.

[image: com.domain.X<T> Parameters: <T>]

Is there any way to show the generic type constraints from the Javadoc viewer in Eclipse?

Comment: Why would you like to document something that is self explanatory in its declaration itself?

Comment: @edalorzo In Eclipse, when you hover on an element, only the Javadoc shows, and the element's (unconstrained) signature.  I'd like to see it in the Javadoc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I entered an [Eclipse bug/enhancement](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=375542) to address this issue.  Incredibly, Markus Keller actually implemented/fixed this within 3-4 hours of the submission!

Answer (score 0):

The class's body already says that `T extends Object`, you don't need it in the javadoc.

When documenting things (comments in code or javadoc etc.), follow these 2 rules:

- **Don't repeat yourself**. If you don't follow this, then it will be a lot harder to keep comments and code in sync.
- **Don't document what's obvious**. The readers of your code know the language. Instead of explaining for example that you did a cast, explain **WHY** you did a cast.

Comment: It seems that this is an irritating limitation of Eclipse's Javadoc implementation.  I agree that I shouldn't have to manually document it in my Javadoc just because Eclipse doesn't add this information to the displayed Javadoc.

Comment: I've rewritten the question appropriately, so please feel free to delete your answer.